# How to add attendees to an outlook.com calendar event programmatically

Tags: rest, calendar, outlook.com

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx#cal_rest) documentation provides the endpoint for creating the event in my own calendar. But how can attendees be added to the event?

I am looking at something similar to what Google calendar provides [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) with the attendees array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever figured out if this is possible? I'm having this issue now.